# How can i create a java web service that supports multiple client requests using only java SE?

Tags: java, web-services

I have the task of creating a web service that takes requests from multiple clients. I am new to web services so i used this tutorial:

http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/web-service/1145-how-create-java-web-service.html

This is exactly what i am looking for. A web service with no java ee.

It is preferable that is stick with java se, it's a policy that is prefered to be kept.

Now i would like to go one step further and implement the service so that it processes requests from multiple clients that operate on a shared resource.

Ideally i would like something like this:

```
 Client client = new Client();
 client.processRequest(string);
```

And the web service will process the requests in the order they arrive. The requests will come in as an request is processed so it will be kept in a stack.

The problem is i just on't know how to send the response back to the specific client. The response will be a string. The only thing i came up with, at least in principle, is to send a object that remembers where it came from but that just seems the web services job.

I have searched the internet but did not find a solution.

If possible using only SE please help. 
If you think it is not possible without EE you can say so, but i would very much like an answer using only SE

Comment: That policy is nonsensical, JavaEE is only a specification that envelops a set of APIs and standards, of which JAX-WS is one. So if you use that singular API you're pulling a bit of the JEE specification into your application. And guess what a JEE container such as Glassfish is built with? Its a JavaSE application. Its all the same: Java. So creating policies that exclude one or the other are a failure from the get-go and just prove that the platform is not understood.

Comment: @Gimby Perhaps i should have been more explicit, the reason for this is because for this project intellij idea community edition is used which does not support java ee. Now obviously there can be some arguments made that the IDE doesn't matter as much, but the fact is that it would be much more difficult to use the base api's and standards of java EE using IDEA community. IF it is not possible i will use eclipse instead of building from scratch. But I was given the fact that it is very preferable to use only java SE.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to implement is an Asynchronous Webservice. The following link tells you how to implement it in Java SE.

http://java.dzone.com/articles/asynchronous-java-se-web

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [Endpoint.publish](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Endpoint.html#publish-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) methods in Java SE.  First, you create a simple "endpoint interface":

```
package com.example;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public interface ExampleService {
    String getDateTime();
}
```

Then you specify that interface in an implementation class.  As you can see, both classes must be annotated with [@WebService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/jws/WebService.html).

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.example.ExampleService",
            serviceName = "ExampleService",
            portName = "timeService",
            targetNamespace = "http://example.com/time")
public class ExampleServiceImpl
implements ExampleService {
    public String getDateTime() {
        return String.format("%tc", System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws IOException {
        // Create server
        Endpoint endpoint =
            Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/example",
                             new ExampleServiceImpl());

        URL wsdl = new URL("http://localhost:8080/example?wsdl");

        // Create client
        Service service = Service.create(wsdl,
            new QName("http://example.com/time", "ExampleService"));
        ExampleService e = service.getPort(ExampleService.class);

        // Test it out
        System.out.println(e.getDateTime());

        endpoint.stop();
    }
}
```

By default, JAX-WS will treat all public methods of an endpoint interface as web methods (since that is commonly what developers will want).  You can have more control by placing the [@WebMethod](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/jws/WebMethod.html) annotation on only the methods you want exposed as web services.

See the [JAX-WS specification](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=224) for all the details.